# Program that will run continuously without any condition

Tags: swift

I want to write code in swift in xcode, which should has button function and others, but the code should has function, which will run continuously without any condition. Is there any chance to do this?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean. Please be more specific—and add code so that we can see what you’ve already tried.

Comment: @TomE I have not any code, I am just asking, for which method or solution i should looking for. For example...In the app will be video transmission in real time and the program should be able to search for the largest gap and write these data into memory.

Comment: If  you want code to run continuously you might want a loop (as in while-loop) which runs in a background thread so you don't block the UI. Everytime the UI should update, you will have to dispatch the changing activities back to the UI-thread.

Comment: @TMob while is not what I want. When the while cycle is running, nothing else can be running to. But I want to let one function run all the time and at the same time there has to be possibility to use another function. But when I use another function, the first function has to be running to.

Comment: But that is exactly what multiple threads do. You can have one thread run function 1 and another thread run function 2. It would be easier to explain, if you could give me a specific implementation usecase

Comment: If you want to learn more about multi-threading, here's a good place to start. https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1

Comment: @TMob thank you, this is what I want

Comment: Cool. I'll add it as answer. Please mark it as solved if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want code to run continuously you might want a loop (as in while-loop) which runs in a background thread so you don't block the UI. Everytime the UI should update, you will have to dispatch the changing activities back to the UI-thread.

For a general tutorial to swift-multithreading refer to
https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1